# Getting value from json response Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

```
[{
  "_text" = "turn off the air con";
  confidence = "0.609";
  entities =     {
      "on_off" =         (
                    {
              value = off;
          }
      );
  };
  intent = "aircond_temperature";
}]
```

I have a json response named "outcomes", and I would like to extract the "off" value from "on_off".

So far what I've done is to get the first element from the response and then cast it to an NSDictionary which works fine, and then using object for key to get the values of each dictionary, and casting them to their respective types.

```
let firstOutcome:NSDictionary = outcomes.first as! NSDictionary
let intent:String = firstOutcome.objectForKey("intent") as! String
let entities:NSDictionary = firstOutcome.objectForKey("entities") as! NSDictionary
```

But when it comes to entities I have no idea what type should I cast "on_off" to. Any ideas?

Comment: please post working son atleast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your "on_off" key contain array of dictionaries, so you could try to access it by using this code.

```
let entities:NSDictionary = firstOutcome.objectForKey("entities") as! NSDictionary
let onOff = entities["on_off"] as! NSArray
let firstValue = onOff.firstObject as! NSDictionary
print(firstValue["value"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
let entities = entities["on_off"]

for var entity in entities {
    print_r(entity["value"])
}
```

Comment: I did and I get (
        {
        value = off;
    }
)

Answer (score 0):

The brackets tell the whole story. `{` is an object or dictionary, `(` is an array. So, `entities` is a dictionary containing an array of dictionaries, where the inner dictionary has string keys and values.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the explanation